# Angular Js - Checkbox model not toggling on ng-change?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, checkbox, angular-ui

I have a simple checkbox like this:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="userGroup" ng-model="selectedAll" ng-change="selectAll();"></input>
```

I'm initiating the `selectedAll` model to false in my controller. In my selectAll() function, I log the value of the flag. But it stays false, doesn't update when I check and uncheck the checkbox. Any reason and solution for this?

Update:

My controller's code:

```
$scope.selectedAll = false;

$scope.selectAll = function() {
    console.log($scope.selectedAll);
}
```

Comment: Can u pls also include the code of your `controller`

Comment: @RutwickGangurde Your above code works fine for me. Here is a [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/LgL747ph/)

Comment: It might be that your checkbox model is in a different scope.

Comment: The function is in the same scope, and it is called. So how can the model have a different scope?

Comment: @brainwash Your comment made me look into my state configuration and make a minor change that worked!

Answer (score 3):

try using the 'dotted' ng-model:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="userGroup" ng-model="obj.selectedAll" ng-change="selectAll();"></input>
```

-

```
$scope.obj = {
  selectedAll: false
}

$scope.selectAll = function() {
  console.log($scope.obj.selectedAll);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

here I have created a [plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/h9lBZ0luuAhm9fzQflRE?p=preview)

```
<input type="checkbox" name="userGroup" ng-model="selectedAll" ng-change="selectAll();"></input>
{{selectedAll}}
```

Its changing flag also i am getting updated value on ng-change

Comment: Isn't this what I am doing?

Comment: Which angular version your are using?

Comment: @RutwickGangurde Can you show us a plnkr or jsfiddle demonstrating your issue?

Comment: The plunkr @dhavalcengg has posted is the exact same code!

Answer (score 0):

I found out the issue. I'm using angular-ui-router for routing. The checkbox in question is in one state view (View B), which is controlled by this controller. The controller is used by some other state view (View A) as well. In my state configuration, I had specified this as the controller for the View A, but not for the View B, because it is the child of view A and it is supposed to inherit the controller. Just specified the controller explicitly for view B and everything started working.

To simplify:

```
A (normal view) > B(child view, contains checkbox)

.state('viewa', {
    url: '/viewa',
    templateUrl: '...',
    controller: 'someCtrl'
})

.state('viewa.viewb', {
    url: '/viewb',
    templateUrl: '...',
    controller: 'someCtrl' //ADDED THE CONTROLLER HERE
});
```

I hope this helps someone who is using angular ui router and faces the same problem.